# Formulas, approximations, or bounds for $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\lVert X \rVert} \right)$, $X\sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$?

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, moments, circular-statistics, quadratic-form

In another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4784989/formulas-or-approximations-for-mathbbe-left-fracx-x-right-or-m), I asked for $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\lVert X \rVert} \right)$, in the case where $X \in \mathbb{R}^d \sim N(\mu, I_{d})$. Somebody posted an exact formula based on the symmetry of the isotropic covariance case.

I am now interested in obtaining some expression (or approximation) for the more general case where $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ and $\Sigma$ is any diagonal matrix.

As I mentioned in [this related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629670/formulas-or-approximations-for-mathbbe-left-fracx-x-right-x-si), one possible approximation involves using a [Taylor approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables), in which:
$\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{A}{B} \right) \approx \frac{\mathbb{E}(A)}{\mathbb{E}(B)} - \frac{Cov(A,B)}{\mathbb{E}(B)^2} + \frac{\mathbb{E}(A)var(B)}{\mathbb{E}(B)^3}$, where I would have $A = X$ and $B = ||X||$ in the description above. For using this approximation, however, I'm not sure about the required $\mathbb{E}\left( ||X|| \right)$, $Var \left( ||X|| \right)$ and $Cov(X, ||X||)$ (the first two are related to the [non-central chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution) which has known moments, but I'm not sure I can use this distribution since each $X_i$ has a different variance).

So, I'm wondering whether there is some other reasonable way to approximate $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\lVert X \rVert} \right)$, or whether the missing pieces in the approach I propose above can be obtained.

Of note, the random variable $\frac{X}{||X||}$ with $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ and any $\Sigma$ is the [general projected normal distribution](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bayesian-analysis/volume-12/issue-1/The-General-Projected-Normal-Distribution-of-Arbitrary-Dimension--Modeling/10.1214/15-BA989.pdf).

**Edit:**
The approach proposed in the comments of using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality could be useful. For that, we'd need $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{||X||^2}\right)$ which is a challenging problem (see [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1467-842X.1986.tb00604.x), [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1467-842X.1988.tb00854.x)).

Comment: The Spectral Theorem asserts you can always take $\Sigma$ to be diagonal.

Comment: Would lower and/or upper bounds on $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\lVert X \rVert} \right)$ be useful? If so, then you can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to get these bounds by noting that $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\| X \|} \right) = \mathbb{E}\left(X \cdot \frac{1}{\| X \|} \right)$.

Comment: They would be useful. Formatting in the expression you wrote didn't go well. Mind fixing it?

Comment: @dherrera is it better now?

Comment: That bound could be useful. It would require having an expression for $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{||X||^2}\right)$ though. As mentioned in the comments of this other question I posted (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630598/moments-of-sum-of-squares-of-independent-gaussians-x-i-sim-mathcaln-mu-i), there's a simple formula for $\mathbb{E}(||X||^2)$, but not sure about $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{||X||^2}\right)$? There is a formula for all moments of non-centered chi-squared (i.e. $||X||^2$), but I'm not sure I can use that distribution for the case with a general diagonal $\Sigma$ here.

Comment: @dherrera you're right. I initially thought that computing $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{||X||^2}\right)$ would be straight-forward. If you do find an answer to your question, I would appreciate it if you can share it. This seems to be an interesting problem...

Comment: Each component of $E[X/\|X\|]$ is of the form $f(U,V)=U/\sqrt{U^2+V}$, where $U$ is that component of $X$ and $V=(\sum X_i^2)-U^2$. So you can approximate $f$ by its second-order Taylor series around $(E[U],E[V])$, and take the expectation of that Taylor series. This estimates that component of $E[X/\|X\|]$ as $E[U]/\sqrt{E[U]^2+E[V]}$ times a polynomial in $E[U]$, $E[V]$, $Var[U]$, $Var[V]$. That whole expression may be too messy for insight, but it can be straightforwardly calculated in terms of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$.

Comment: Thanks @MattF., I'll try to implement what you say. If you write it as an answer (the final formula) and it works, I will add +50 to the bounty and award it your way.

Comment: @MattF. I tried the Taylor approximation and it seems to work very good for the case of diagonal covariance matrix!! Brilliant. If you eventually wish to write it as an answer, lmk. I can also share the formulas for the derivatives, variances and expected values.

Comment: @dherrera feel free to share your full analysis in case you don’t get an answer. I’m sure other stats.SE users would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @mhdadk yes, sure. I'll give the commenter an opportunity to post and get some credit for having the key insight, but if they don't post an answer I'll post the answer. Either way, I will also probably include some simulation results.

Comment: What is the typical size of $\mu$ compared to $\Sigma$? This is a projection of $X$ into the unit sphere. You might linearize it if $\mu$ is large and $\Sigma$ is small, such that the angle between $\mu$ and $X$ is small.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus $\mu$ can have any size compared to $\Sigma$ in my problem of interest.

Comment: @mhdadk Just posted the full analysis.

Comment: @dherrera thank you!

Comment: @dherrera if linearization is an acceptable solution, then $\mu$ is apparently not of any size and sufficiently large enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following one of the comments, we can approximate $\mathrm{E}\left( \frac{X}{||X||} \right)$ with $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ by using a second-order Taylor series.

Each element $i$ of the vector $\mathrm{E}\left( \frac{X}{||X||} \right)$ is given by $\mathrm{E}\left( \frac{X_i}{||X||} \right)$. Thus, we can solve the problem by finding the expected value of $f(u,v) = \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v}}$, where $u=X_i$ and $v=\sum_{i=1 }^{i=n} X_j^2 - X_i^2= \sum_{j \neq i} X_j^2$.

The [Taylor approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) for $\mathrm{E}(f(u,v))$ has general form:

$$\mathrm{E}(f(u,v)) \approx f(\hat{u},\hat{v}) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2}\bigg|_{\substack{u=\hat{u}\\v=\hat{v}}}  Var(u) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2}\bigg|_{\substack{u=\hat{u}\\v=\hat{v}}} Var(v) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}\bigg|_{\substack{u=\hat{u}\\v=\hat{v}}} Cov(u,v)$$

where $\hat{u}=\mathrm{E}(u)$, $\hat{v}=\mathrm{E}(v)$ and the partial derivatives of $f(u,v)$ are evaluated at $u=\hat{u}$ and $v=\hat{v}$.

So we need to compute the second-order derivatives of $f$, and also the moments $\mathrm{E}(u)$, $\mathrm{E}(v)$, $Var(u)$, $Var(v)$, $Cov(u,v)$.

The second-derivatives are as follows:

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} = \frac{-3uv}{(u^2+v)^{5/2}} \mathrm{;}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2} = \frac{3u}{4(u^2+v)^{5/2}}  \mathrm{;}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v} = \frac{u^2-\frac{v}{2}}{(u^2+v)^{5/2}}$$

Then, the moments of $u$ are the moments of $X_i$, so $\hat{u}=\mu_i$ and $Var(u)=\Sigma_{i,i}$. The moments involving $v$ can be obtained using moments of [quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)). Because $v$ is just a sum of squares of $X$ removing $X_i$, we denote $\mu_v$ the vector $\mu$ with element $i$ removed, and $\Sigma_v$ the matrix $\Sigma$ with row and column $i$ removed, for readable formulas. Then the formulas for the moments of $v$ are:

$$\hat{v} = \mathrm{E}(v) = tr(\Sigma_v) + \mu_v' \mu_v = \sum_{j\neq i} \left( \mu_j^2 + \Sigma_{j,j} \right)$$

$$Var(v) = 2 tr(\Sigma_v \Sigma_v) + 4\mu_v \Sigma_v \mu_v$$

For $Cov(u,v)$, we can use the [formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/624386/covariance-of-quadratic-form-and-a-random-vector-of-type-mathbfg-mathbfy/630117#630117) for the covariance between a quadratic form $X' A X$ with $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and a linear form $a'X$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. We set $A$ to be $1$ on the diagonal entries other than $i,i$, and 0 elsewhere (i.e. the identity matrix with a 0 in the $i$th diagonal element), and we set $a$ to be $1$ in entry $i$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then we have that:

$$Cov(u,v) = \sum_{j \neq i} \mu_j \Sigma_{j,i}$$

Thus, to find $\mathrm{E}\left( \frac{X_i}{||X||} \right)$ we compute the moments above, evaluate $f$ and its second derivatives at $(\hat{u},\hat{v})$, and just plug in the terms into the Taylor approximation formula.

For the case of diagonal $\Sigma$ (where $\Sigma_{j,j} = \sigma_j^2$) the expressions simplify:

$$Var(v) = \sum_{j=1}^{j=n} \left[ 2 \sigma_j^4 + 4\mu_j^2 \sigma_j^2 \right] - 2\sigma_i^4 - 4\mu_i^2\sigma_i^2 $$
$$Cov(u,v)=0$$

then, nice, efficient vectorized formulas can be used to compute $\mathrm{E}\left( \frac{X}{||X||} \right)$. Maybe there's also nice vectorized formulas for the non-diagonal $\Sigma$ case, I haven't tried to solve through that yet.

The method works remarkably well in the cases I've tried so far (with diagonal $\Sigma$).

Comment: Very good.  Just a small typo:  In $Var(v)$ the term $\mu_j^2 \sigma_j^2$ should be $4\mu_j^2 \sigma_j^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two special cases that might be used to check on the Taylor series approximations a bit faster and more accurate than using simulations (using *Mathematica*).

**Special case:  $n=2$.**

Suppose $X_i\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ for $i=1,2$.  We find the joint density for $Z_1=X_1/\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$ and $Z_2=\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$ from which we find the marginal density for $Z_1$ and then use numerical integration to find the mean of $Z_1$.

```
(* Format indexed variables for output to be more readable *)
Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]
Format[z[n_]] := Subscript[z, n]
Format[μ[n_]] := Subscript[μ, n]
Format[σ[n_]] := Subscript[σ, n]

(* Define joint distribution *)
dist = TransformedDistribution[{x[1]/Sqrt[x[1]^2 + x[2]^2], 
    Sqrt[x[1]^2 + x[2]^2]},
   {x[1] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[1], σ[1]], 
    x[2] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[2], σ[2]]}];

(* Joint pdf of z[1]=x[1]/Sqrt[x[1]^2+x[2]^2] and z[2]=Sqrt[x[1]^2+x[2]^2] *)
jointPDF = PDF[dist, {z[1], z[2]}][[1, 1, 1]]
```

[image: Joint pdf of Z1 and Z2]

```
(* Marginal pdf of z[1] by integrating out z[2] *)
a = {μ[1] ∈ Reals, μ[2] ∈ Reals, σ[1] > 0, σ[2] > 0, -1 < z[1] < 1};
pdfz1 = FullSimplify[Integrate[jointPDF, {z[2], 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> a],  Assumptions -> a]
```

[image: Marginal pdf of Z1]

```
(* For any specific values of the parameters one can use numerical integration to find the mean *)
parms = {μ[1] -> 4, μ[2] -> 3, σ[1] -> 2, σ[2] ->  1/2};
mean = NIntegrate[z[1] pdfz1 /. parms, {z[1], -1, 1}]
(* 0.7233206280335711 *)
```

**Special case: $n>1$ and $\sigma_i^2=\sigma_2^2$ for $i=2,\ldots,n$**

Here we have $X_1\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)$ and $X_i\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma^2_2)$ for $i=2,\ldots,n$.  We define $V=\sum_{i=2}^n X_i^2$ where $V$ has a noncentral $\chi^2$ distribution with parameters $n-1$ and $\lambda=\sum_{i=2}^n \mu_i^2$.  So $Z_1=X_1/\sqrt{X_1^2+V}$ and $Z_2=\sqrt{X_1^2+\sigma_2^2 V}$.  We find the joint density of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$.  With specific parameters there is a closed-form for the marginal density of $Z_1$ but it's messy and numerical integration is still necessary to find the mean of $Z_1$.  So we set parameters and numerically integrate the joint distribution of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$.

```
dist1 = TransformedDistribution[{x[1]/Sqrt[x[1]^2 + σ[2]^2 v], 
    Sqrt[x[1]^2 + σ[2]^2 v]},
   {x[1] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[1], σ[1]],
    v \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[n - 1, Sum[μ[i]^2/σ[2]^2, {i, 2, n}]]}];
jointPDF = FullSimplify[PDF[dist1, {z1, z2}][[1, 1, 1]],
  Assumptions -> {z2 > 0, -1 < z1 < 1, σ[1] > 0, σ[2] > 0}]
```

[image: Joint pdf of Z1 and Z2]

```
(* Set parameters *)
parms = {n -> 4, μ[1] -> 2, μ[2] -> 3, μ[3] -> 1/2, μ[4] -> 5, σ[1] -> 3, σ[2] -> 4};

(* Perform numerical integration *)
integrand = z1 jointPDF //. parms
```

[image: Joint pdf of Z1 and Z2 with specified parameters]

```
mean = NIntegrate[integrand, {z1, -1, 1}, {z2, 0, ∞}]
(* 0.216965 *)

(* Check with simulations *)
SeedRandom[12345];
nsim = 1000000;
x1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ[1], σ[1]] /. parms, nsim];
x2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ[2], σ[2]] /. parms, nsim];
x3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ[3], σ[2]] /. parms, nsim];
x4 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ[4], σ[2]] /. parms, nsim];
Mean[x1/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2]]
(* 0.216869 *)
```