# Moments of sum of squares of independent gaussians $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma^2_i)$, or $||X||^2$

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, moments, chi-squared-distribution, quadratic-form

Say that we have $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$.  Is there some formula to calculate analytically the expected value of the sum $S = \sum_i^n X_i^2$?. This is equivalent to computing $\mathbb{E}\left(||X||^2 \right)$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Lambda)$ and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries $\Lambda_{ii} = \sigma_i^2$.

From the above, we know that each $\frac{X_i^2}{\sigma_i^2} \sim \chi^2_1\left( \frac{\mu^2}{\sigma_i^2} \right)$, where $\chi^2_1(\lambda)$ is the  [non-central chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) distribution with 1 degree of freedom and non-centrality parameter $\lambda$.

I am interested in this problem following several answers to related problems (e.g. [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67533/sum-of-noncentral-chi-square-random-variables), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442916/948036)), showing that the probability distribution of this sum, $S = \sum_i^n X_i^2$, or equivalently, of $||X||^2$ is very complicated, being related to the [generalized chi squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution). But I'm wondering whether, as opposed to the distribution, the expected value (and hopefully some other moments too) have simpler expressions.

Comment: Is a $\chi^2$ - without non-centrality - even supported for non-integral degrees of freedom? I think not. Therefore there are some constraints to state before you can even deal with summing non-central, non-identical RVs.

Comment: The initial question looks too simple: since $E[X_i^2]=\operatorname{Var}(X_i)+E[X_i]^2 = 1+1^2 = 2,$ then $E[S] = 2\sum_i w_i$ whether or not the $w_i$ are positive.  Are you sure you have asked the question you intended?

Comment: why don't you formulate your question in a simpl yet general form?

Comment: @whuber good point, I see now OP asked about the sum's expectation. It was so easy, I thought they were asking about the general distribution... which is too hard :D

Comment: @whuber answer is right. I got caught up in how complicated the actual distribution is, and completely missed the trivial formula for the expected value. But that was my intended question. However, despite seeing a lot of questions about the distribution of $||X||^2$ for $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ in this site, I hadn't found one for $\mathbb{E}(||X||^2)$. I edited the question to be about the more general and useful case. If this is not a duplicate of another question, do you want to post your answer @whuber?

Comment: If not, I'm happy to post your comment as an answer @whuber

Comment: @AdamO - why not?  A chi-squared distribution is just a gamma distribution with parameters presented differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the answer is obtained using basic probability.

We have that $\mathbb{E}\left[ X_i^2 \right] = \mathrm{Var}(X_i) + \mathbb{E}\left[X_i \right]^2$. Also, we have that, for independent $Y_i$, $\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_i Y_i \right] = \sum_i \mathbb{E} \left[ Y_i \right]$. Putting these two facts together, for $X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \Lambda \right)$ where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal covariance matrix with elements $\Lambda_{ii} = \sigma_i^2$:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ ||X||^2  \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_i^n X_i^2 \right] = \sum_i^n (\sigma_i^2 + \mu_i^2).$$